# Kinesis video consumer in android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am currently developing an android app which live streams the video to the kinesis video streams and the ability to play the stream in some other devices.

**What i did:** 
I followed the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-android.html and was able to stream the video to the kinesis stream, which i could see in the stream dashboard page.

Now to consume the stream and play it in the device i found the java sample of it - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/parser-library.html. After some trial and error i was able to render the video in the JFrame.

**Question:** 
My question is, isn't there an end-to-end support to produce and consume the kinesis video streams completely in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kinesis Data Firehouse service through which you can store kinesis data stream to S3 or redshift & can request the stream through android app

Link for the reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-android-kinesis-data-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no example for rendering consumer in Android but the [Consumer Parser library](https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/utilities/H264FrameRenderer.java#L62) uses JCodec to decode H264 frames for rendering which supports Android as well. You can fine tune the consumer parser library to use [Android version of JCodec](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/tree/master/android) to decode or you can also use the Android's native [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) to decode frames. Once the image is decoded, you can use ImageView to display images or re-package video frames into to MP4 and use VideoView to display video.

Comment: Did you get success on this kinesis video stream ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Yes.

Comment: Can you please guide me ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Sure. Can you tell me where are you stuck? Also one easy way to playback is using HLS or DASH so you dont have to worry about parsing, decoding etc. 
Kinesis Video HLS : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/hls-playback.html  HLS in Android:  https://www.toptal.com/apple/introduction-to-http-live-streaming-hls Kinesis Video DASH: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/dash-playback.html DASH in android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer

Comment: @BabuPrasad I am stuck trying to get audio from AWS connect, I am getting the endpoint, then get api media, but i am unable to create that payload into a non corrupted audio file